# can the agora virtual background sdk be usedd with WebRTC protocol

Tags: background, sdk, webrtc, integration, agora.io

```
I want to integrate the Virtual Background feature into my application.My website uses WebRTC protocol but the virtual background sdk uses the RTMP protocol.So is it possible for me to somehow integrate this virtual background sdk into my application?If yes, how do i do so?
```

SDK link :
https://www.agora.io/en/blog/agora-io-sdk-version-2-3-av-fallback-background-images-and-more-in-this-release

Comment: As Hermes mentioned, the Agora virtual backgrounds SDK is not for WebRTC. If the original question is how to integrate the Virtual Background feature into your application, there are other projects like BodyPix, as well as several commercial vendors you can search on google for, which do have integrations with WebRTC applications

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the feature you are referring to in the link. 
This feature is not segmentation based virtual backgrounds, it's meant for use when pushing streams from Agora.io to a 3rd party RTMP url.

In the [setLiveTranscoding configuration](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1live_1_1_live_transcoding.html#a63089743805231839d1cc38496dccd07) you would set a background image and when Agora composites multiple streams into one of its predefined templates, so the videos display in the given configuration and you can add a background image behind the streams so it's not black if one of the streams stops broadcasting.

> ***AgoraImage io.agora.rtc.live.LiveTranscoding.backgroundImage:***
>   The background image added to the CDN live publishing stream. Once a background image is added, the audience of the CDN live publishing stream can see it. See AgoraImage.